# HTML and CSS table is getting wrong style by inheritance

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've got a HTML/CSS code, which reacts a little weird (in my opinion). Or I just don't understand inheritance of styles.

The following code snippet is what causes the problem:

[image]

You can see I've got a table with the class formula. and on the right side you can see that every `table.formular` td gets a padding.

Below, in one of the tds of the formular table I've got a new table with the class tabelle-rubrikbar. This table contains a td with the class `customSearch-InnerTable-td` which should overwrite the padding. But in this case the inherited formular td is overwriting the `customSearch-InnerTable-td`.

Comment: You should include sufficient code as text in the question, instead of a mere partial screenshot. In this case, there happens to be sufficient information to guess what the real problem is (it has nothing to do with inheritance).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use an higher specificity for your rule, e.g.

```
table.formular td.customSearch-InnerTable-td { ... }
```

For further explanation see http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: I think td.customSearch-InnerTable-td will be enough

Comment: it's not enough since his first rule is `table.formular td`

Comment: Works for chrome, thanks. But IE won't accept that this is higher priority :(

Comment: @Loki: why not? this is css should overwrite the previous one even on IE6. Or are you talking about a specific issue/bug?

Comment: Ah IE had the css in cache. That's why it didn't work. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Just be more specific with your declaration. The more you narrow down the css style the higher gets is priority over other styles

It behaves like this:

`td < td.class` so give your class a higher priority like

`.tabelle-rubrikbar tr td.customSearch-InnterTable-td`

Comment: that example was not like "use this style" it was just to clarify that the `td.class`  style got higher priority than just `td`

Comment: I withdrew my comment.

Answer (score -1):

You should try adding `!important` at the end of `customSearch-InnerTable-td` like

```
customSearch-InnerTable-td {
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;}
```

Comment: Try reading up here - [link] (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules)

Comment: Don't use !important unless you don't have other choice!

Answer (score -2):

mark the css of the customSearch-InnerTable-td as "!important" (without the quotes) and it will increase the priority of the styling you have used in the customSearch-InnerTable-td. Its a small hack which works fine always